# Is there a way to "interrupt" an enumerate/itemize environment?

Tags: enumerate, itemize

Is there a way to have a normally indented paragraph in the middle of an enumerate/itemize environment? Something more elegant that manually numbering the `\item`s, or a clean way to tinker with counters? Here's what I mean:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Numbered as One

    \item Numbered as Two

It would be really cool to take a break from numbering
and have a normally (further left) indented paragraph here.

    \item Numbered as Three
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The  `enumitem` package defines the `resume` and `resume*` keys.

Answer (score 1):

Use `enumitem` not `enumerate` and then you can end the list and restart using its `resume` option.